# Golang net-http spawn multiple tcp session

Tags: go, tcp, net-http

In the below [snippet](https://play.golang.org/p/8gTnmoTBnr) I tried to perform GET request using POOL of worker.

I thought it will reuse the TCP session instead of creating new one for every worker, but it creates multiple session.

Could someone please help in validating the code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "sync"
)

//var URL = "http://localhost:8181/api/v1/resources"
var URL = "http://httpbin.org/ip"

// Task interface
type Task interface {
    Execute(p *Pool)
}

// JobDesc struct
type JobDesc struct {
    Client *http.Client
}

// Pool struct
type Pool struct {
    mu      sync.Mutex
    size    int
    tasks   chan Task
    kill    chan struct{}
    wg      sync.WaitGroup
    Results chan interface{}
}

// Methods for Pool struct.
func (p *Pool) worker() {
    defer p.wg.Done()
    for {
        select {
        case task, ok := <-p.tasks:
            if !ok {
                return
            }
            task.Execute(p)

        case <-p.kill:
            return
        }
    }
}

// Resize methods update the number of goroutine in the pool, to execute the task.
func (p *Pool) Resize(n int) {
    p.mu.Lock()
    defer p.mu.Unlock()
    for p.size < n {
        p.size++
        p.wg.Add(1)
        go p.worker()
    }
    for p.size > n {
        p.size--
        p.kill <- struct{}{}
    }
}

// CloseJobChannel method close the jobs channel,
// once all the jobs are sending to the channel.
func (p *Pool) CloseJobChannel() {
    close(p.tasks)
}

// CloseResultChannel method close the results channel,
// once all the jobs are completed and results are collected.
func (p *Pool) CloseResultChannel() {
    close(p.Results)
}

// Wait Method of Pool struct
func (p *Pool) Wait() {
    p.wg.Wait()
}

// AddJob Method add task to the task channel
func (p *Pool) AddJob(task Task) {
    p.tasks <- task
}

// NewPool function create pool of task base on the size
// provided.
func NewPool(size int) *Pool {
    pool := &Pool{
        tasks:   make(chan Task, 10000),
        kill:    make(chan struct{}),
        Results: make(chan interface{}, 10000),
    }
    pool.Resize(size)
    return pool
}

// Execute to execute
func (job *JobDesc) Execute(p *Pool) {
    res, err := job.Client.Get(URL)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    //body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    fmt.Println(res.Body)
    //defer res.Body.Close()
}

func main() {
    pool := NewPool(10)
    tr := &http.Transport{DisableKeepAlives: false}
    client := &http.Client{Transport: tr}

    for i := 1; i <= 50; i++ {
        job := JobDesc{Client: client}
        pool.AddJob(&job)
    }
    pool.CloseJobChannel()
    pool.Wait()
    pool.CloseResultChannel()
    i := 1
    for k := range pool.Results {
        fmt.Printf("%d, %d", i, k)
        i++
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're making up to 10 concurrent calls to the server. Since you can't make simultaneous requests on the same connection, it's going to make multiple connections.

Comment: oh could you please recommend any better way to GET or POST faster with multiple thread.

Comment: What's wrong with using multiple connections? That's the only way to send more than 1 request at a time.

Comment: as per the docs https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/,   Clients and Transports are safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines and for efficiency should only be created once and re-used.

Comment: When i have 100k docs to post, and it creates 100K session which is not possible.

Comment: btw this is working in python to reuse session.

Comment: If you send these serially it _will_ work exactly like it would in python. If you want concurrent connections you need to limit concurrency to a reasonable level, and be able to maintain that many connections in the Transport. Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39813587/go-client-program-generates-a-lot-a-sockets-in-time-wait-state/39834253#39834253

Comment: Let me read, thank you so much.

Comment: @jimB That works after tweaking MaxIdleConnsPerHost and MaxIdleConns. Hope you may write few words in the answer, so i can mark as answer and who ever come across can get it easily.

Comment: @jimB it works for GET request but not with POST request. Got, panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Comment: a nil pointer deterrence is an error in your code. Please show the code and where the panic happens.

Comment: Here is the one  for get request, it works intermittently https://play.golang.org/p/7oqInVO0XR   and throwing this `error  [Get : unsupported protocol scheme ""]
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x28b7]

goroutine 11 [running]:`

Comment: it would really help if you show where the actual panic occurred, but it's probably from your Execute method, where you continue executing after an error and `res` is probably `nil`.