# Limiting concurrency when processing messages from RabbitMQ

Tags: go

I'm attempting to read URLs from a queue (RabbitMQ) and make a limited number of concurrent HTTP requests i.e. have a pool of 10 workers making concurrent requests to URLs received from the queue (forever).

So far I've implemented a consumer as per the RabbitMQ tutorials:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-go.html

And have tried a number of methods from examples discovered on the web, ending at the example here:
http://jmoiron.net/blog/limiting-concurrency-in-go/

Unfortunately, my current code runs for approximately one minute and then freezes indefinitely. I've tried adding/moving go routines around but I can't seem to get it to work as intended (I'm very new to Go).

Current code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"

    "github.com/Xide/bloom"
    "github.com/streadway/amqp"
)

func failOnError(err error, msg string) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("%s: %s", msg, err)
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("%s: %s", msg, err))
    }
}

var netClient = &http.Client{
    Timeout: time.Second * 10,
}

func getRequest(url string) {
    //resp, err := http.Get(string(url))
    resp, err := netClient.Get(string(url))
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("HTTP request error: %s", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("StatusCode:", resp.StatusCode)
    fmt.Println(resp.Request.URL)
}

func main() {
    bf := bloom.NewDefaultScalable(0.1)

    conn, err := amqp.Dial("amqp://127.0.0.1:5672/")
    failOnError(err, "Failed to connect to RabbitMQ")
    defer conn.Close()

    ch, err := conn.Channel()
    failOnError(err, "Failed to open a channel")
    defer ch.Close()

    q, err := ch.QueueDeclare(
        "urls",            // name
        true,              // durable
        false,             // delete when unused
        false,             // exclusive
        false,             // no-wait
        nil,               // arguments
    )
    failOnError(err, "Failed to declare a queue")

    err = ch.Qos(
        1,     // prefetch count
        0,     // prefetch size
        false, //global
    )
    failOnError(err, "Failed to set Qos")

    msgs, err := ch.Consume(
        q.Name, // queue
        "",     // consumer
        false,  // auto-ack
        false,  // exclusive
        false,  // no-local
        false,  // no-wait
        nil,    // args
    )
    failOnError(err, "Failed to register a consumer")

    forever := make(chan bool)

    concurrency := 10
    sem := make(chan bool, concurrency)
    go func() {
        for d := range msgs {
            sem <- true
            url := string(d.Body)
            if bf.Match(url) == false {
                bf.Feed(url)
                log.Printf("Not seen: %s", d.Body)
                go func(url string) {
                    defer func() { <-sem }()
                    getRequest(url)
                }(url)
            } else {
                log.Printf("Already seen: %s", d.Body)
            }
            d.Ack(false)
        }
        for i := 0; i < cap(sem); i++ {
            sem <- true
        }
    }()

    log.Printf(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C")
    <-forever
}
```

Comment: could you add the log output to the question, this will help people see what is going on

Comment: Try running the program with `-race` flag, it may help you with debugging: https://blog.golang.org/race-detector

Comment: With concurrency set to 10 it makes approx 60 HTTP requests (getting gradually slower) and then freezes. Building with -race doesn't provide any info.

Comment: [net/http documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http) says "The client must close the response body when finished with it:" and I can't spot in your code, where you close the response body. So I conjecture, that all those connection stay open indefinitly. (But with only 60 calls, that shouldn't already be a problem.)

Comment: If I remember correcty, there are also problems, if you don't read the body of the response fully, but I can't find the documentation pointing to that. But I remember doing things like `io.Copy(resp.Body, ioutil.Discard)` or something. Maybe that was superstition.

Comment: @Krom not superstition - if you don't read the entire response body before closing it, the connection will not be reused for subsequent requests to the same host: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17948827/reusing-http-connections-in-golang

Answer (score 3):

You're not properly handling your HTTP responses, leading to a growing set of open connections. Try this:

```
func getRequest(url string) {
    resp, err := netClient.Get(string(url))
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("HTTP request error: %s", err)
        return
    }
    // Add this bit:
    defer func() {
        io.Copy(ioutil.Discard, resp.Body)
        resp.Body.Close()
    }()
    fmt.Println("StatusCode:", resp.StatusCode)
    fmt.Println(resp.Request.URL)
}
```

This, after you finish reading messages from the channel, seems unnecessary and potentially problematic:

```
    for i := 0; i < cap(sem); i++ {
        sem <- true
    }
```

Why fill the `sem` channel after you've read all the messages from the queue? You've added exactly as many messages to the channel as you expect to read from it, so this is pointless *at best*, and could cause problems if you make the wrong change to the rest of the code.

Unrelated to your issue, but this is redundant:

```
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("%s: %s", msg, err)
    panic(fmt.Sprintf("%s: %s", msg, err))
}
```

Per [the documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#Fatalf), `Fatalf` already exits, so the `panic` will never be called. If you want to log and `panic`, try [`log.Panicf`](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#Panicf), which is designed for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding to `sem` when you get a message, but only removing from `sem` when you haven't seen a url.

so, once you've "already seen" 10 urls, your app will lock up.
So you need to add `<-sem` to your else statement that logs "Already seen".

Either way, that's a fairly odd way to do this kind of concurrency.
Here's a version that does this in a more idiomatic way [on Play](https://play.golang.org/p/1w69Ebm9WT).

Note, in this version, we just spawn 10 goroutines that listen to the rabbit channel.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"

    "github.com/Xide/bloom"
    "github.com/streadway/amqp"
)

func failOnError(err error, msg string) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("%s: %s", msg, err)
    }
}

var netClient = &http.Client{
    Timeout: time.Second * 10,
}

func getRequest(url string) {
    //resp, err := http.Get(string(url))
    resp, err := netClient.Get(string(url))
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("HTTP request error: %s", err)
        return
    }
    resp.Body.Close()
    fmt.Println("StatusCode:", resp.StatusCode)
    fmt.Println(resp.Request.URL)
}
```

```
func main() {
    bf := bloom.NewDefaultScalable(0.1)

    conn, err := amqp.Dial("amqp://127.0.0.1:5672/")
    failOnError(err, "Failed to connect to RabbitMQ")
    defer conn.Close()

    ch, err := conn.Channel()
    failOnError(err, "Failed to open a channel")
    defer ch.Close()

    q, err := ch.QueueDeclare(
        "urls", // name
        true,   // durable
        false,  // delete when unused
        false,  // exclusive
        false,  // no-wait
        nil,    // arguments
    )
    failOnError(err, "Failed to declare a queue")

    err = ch.Qos(
        1,     // prefetch count
        0,     // prefetch size
        false, //global
    )
    failOnError(err, "Failed to set Qos")

    msgs, err := ch.Consume(
        q.Name, // queue
        "",     // consumer
        false,  // auto-ack
        false,  // exclusive
        false,  // no-local
        false,  // no-wait
        nil,    // args
    )
    failOnError(err, "Failed to register a consumer")

    concurrency := 10
    var wg sync.Waitgroup              // used to coordinate when they are done, ie: if rabbit conn was closed
    for x := 0; x < concurrency; x++ { // spawn 10 goroutines, all reading from the rabbit channel
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done() // signal that this goroutine is done
            for d := range msgs {
                url := string(d.Body)
                if bf.Match(url) == false {
                    bf.Feed(url)
                    log.Printf("Not seen: %s", d.Body)
                    getRequest(url)
                } else {
                    log.Printf("Already seen: %s", d.Body)
                }
                d.Ack(false)
            }
            log.Println("msgs channel closed")
        }()
    }

    log.Printf(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C")
    wg.Wait() // when all goroutine's exit, the app exits
}
```

Comment: The above example exits with: `panic: sync: negative WaitGroup counter` @david-budworth

Comment: Updated the example, I neglected to initialize the Waitgroup with the number of workers (concurrency).   I can't actually run the app as I don't have whatever submits items, so you may have to adjust a bit.   The point was more to show an alternative way and to explain why your solution was hanging.

Comment: `var wg sync.Waitgroup` => `var wg sync.WaitGroup`
and 
add `wg.Add(concurrency)`

Comment: @Cui yes, that is more direct, to just `wg.Add(concurrency)`, but I generally prefer to have an obvious connection between `wg.Add(1)` and `wg.Done()`.  Plus, if I later (incorrectly) change the for loop to be `<= concurrency` the program will still behave correctly, even though it has an off-by-one error in the loop